# String with array format to array

Tags: php

I have a string in the following format.

```
abc.something=1&bcd.something=2&efg.something=3&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something
```

When I use **parse_str** this one all the key values except array are available and, getting an array as an array but first key and last value.

Expected result :

```
   'abc_something' => '1'
   'bcd_something' => '2'
   'efg_something' => '3'
```

Up to this already receiving. rest, i want like as follows, currenctly i'm getting

```
0 => 'lastvalue
```

only

```
 'arr[0]_something_something => 'something'
 'arr[0]_something_something => 'something'
 'arr[0]_something_something => 'something'
```

The same happening even I use **`parse_str`** after applying **`urldecode()`**

```
 $str = 'abc.something=1&bcd.something=2&efg.something=3&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something&arr%5B0%5D.something.something=something';

 $str= urldecode($str);
 parse_str($str, $arr);
```

Comment: who pass array data in get? it is not recommended, I can say get is not there for that purpose. Use post instead.

Comment: @Drakula this is a response from 3rd party.

Comment: It's not valid to have `arr[0].something.something=something`, that's why it's converted to simply `arr[0]=something`. Maybe you are looking for `arr[0][something][something]=something`. Please note that `abc.something` is single key and it's not array construction, HTTP not accepting JS object notation

Comment: @Justinas how can I convert it as you said?

Comment: @NitheesramRajes How are you making this string?

Comment: @Justinas this str is a response I'm receiving from 3rd party.  kindly refer the $str I have defined at the top.